# Collapsing empty lines in a Vim interactive session

Tags: regex, vim, buffer, lines

When interactively editing a Vim buffer, how do I replace each sequence of multiple empty lines (truly empty or containing optional white space) by a single empty line via a *single* substitute command -- preferably without removing any trailing white space from non-empty lines...?

Naturally, such blocks of multiple "empty" lines may live anywhere in the buffer including the very beginning and the very end of the buffer.

Since I'm only interested in tracking down what could be a misunderstanding on my part of the way Vim handles regular expressions, solutions involving some form or other of iteration (Vim's ":global" command, macros, functions..  etc.) are *not* what I am looking for.

---

I need to fix a typo, so I use CTRL-H to try to fix it.. an odd things happen :-)
And when I hit the Enter key to go to the next line, whatever I typed is posted
and I have to use the edit button to add stuff to it. @kev: very interesting
solution and I do have a lot of questions.. but I cannot even reply to your
post.. I just found out my "reputation" is not sufficient.. So you'll have to
wait till I find a way to change that..! I don't suppose there's any way I can
use this forum via a regular mailing list..? I just noticed that I have -176
characters left.. Hence, my initial effort was truncated.. Oh, well..

Answer (score 3):

You can use multi-line pattern:

```
:%s/^\_s*$//
```

`\_s` matches spaces(including new-line)

Comment: Maybe you should replace by `\r` instead of deleting them… Just to match the question.

Comment: @sidyll This command will squeeze serval empty lines to one. Adding `\r` will make two empty lines.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. It looks like I need to find a tutorial to learn how to use this forum. In particular I would need to disable the bizarre shortcuts that make it near impossible to use SO's "editor". For instance, every time I need to fix a typo, I use CTRL-H to try to fix it.. an odd things happen :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. It looks like I need to look for a tutorial to learn how to use this forum. In particular I would need to disable the bizarre shortcuts that make it near impossible to type in a comment. For instance, every time I need to fix a typo, I use CTRL-H to try to fix it.. an odd things happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

@xev..  You are not answering the question.  Your substitute command looks for
empty lines and it replaces them by `//`, in other words by nothing!

You are deleting the lines instead of collapsing them.

If you think this is not the case, just change the `//` in your substitute
command by for instance a string of then dashes..

```
:%s/^\_s*$/----------/
```

You will note that all empty lines get replaced by ten dashes!

Maybe you are running an old buggy version of Vim?

If not, please explain how you think it should work.